# AtomicInteger as Column at Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I use Spring Data JPA and has an entity which has a counter:

```
@JsonIgnore
@Transient
private AtomicInteger accessCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);
```

It is a counter an accessed by multi threads. I want to save its int value at DB when I save that entity. How can I do it?

Comment: At first glance, you definitely should remove `@Transient` for that. Second, you should explain Hibernate how to persist `AtomicInteger` type to some database column, e.g. int.

Comment: I've marked it as @Transient because Hibernate tries to create a tinyblob column. I thought that  I can use another int field for such purpose.